# how to launch a new word docment/excel/power point within Windows Phone 8 app?

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone

How can I launch a new Word/Excel/PowerPoint document within a Windows Phone 8 app?

Here's what I've tried, which doesn't seem to work:

```
await Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(new Uri("ms-word:"));
```

or

```
await Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(new Uri("ms-excel:"));
```

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7143908/1230188

Answer (score 0):

**For WP8**
this may help you.

```
StorageFile pdfFile = await Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation.GetFileAsync("demo.xls");
 // Launch the file.
  Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchFileAsync(pdfFile);
```

Comment: This is for WinRT, OP is asking for Windows Phone.

Comment: @Xyroid  i made changes in my ans

Comment: Would this create a new empty file named 'demo.xls', or do you need to create the file before somehow?

Comment: @malte you need to create file before