# Excel files and Doc files support in Windows Phone Emulator

Tags: excel, c#-4.0, windows-phone-8

I am using Windows Phone 8, Visual Studio 2013,
Here I am getting Excel  files and Doc files as a response.
Are these files supported in Emulator?
I want to show them in user interface.
Thanks!!

This is my code:

```
void SomeMethod()
{
    Uri uri = new Uri("https://www.abc.com/def/xyz");
    WebClient wc = new WebClient();
    wc.DownloadStringAsync(uri);
    wc.DownloadStringCompleted += wc_DownloadStringCompleted;
}

void wc_DownloadStringCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    string result = e.Result.ToString();
    MessageBox.Show(result);
}
```

Comment: Duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21170182/how-to-launch-a-new-word-docment-excel-power-point-within-windows-phone-8-app?rq=1. There are more complete examples of creating a PDF file locally and launching with this technique. It's the same.

Answer (score 2):

Use [Launcher.LaunchFileAsync(IStorageFile)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh701471.aspx) to open the Excel file using the phones default Excel app.